# Google cloud Storage display pdf with php

Tags: php, iframe, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to display a pdf with php in iframe but the file is downloaded.

client code :

```
 <iframe style="height: 700px;width: 80%;margin-left: 100px;" src="<?php echo $publicUrl;?>#zoom=100"></iframe>
```

Backend using php  :

```
App::uses('APIController', 'Controller');
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
$publicFileText = sprintf('new file written at %s', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$options = ['gs' => ['acl' => 'public-read']];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$fileName = "gs://{Project_ID}.appspot.com/test/test.pdf";
file_put_contents($fileName, $publicFileText, 0, $context);
$publicUrl = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($fileName, false);
```

How can i display the pdf file in iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pdf viewer add-ons in your browser. You can check below for more details

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

Comment: wich add-ons ? i can display the pdf in iframe in my local server without any add-ons but when i upload my project in app engine and google storage i found problems.

Comment: Is that downloaded pdf file is valid pdf file? Is ".pdf" extension is there in $publicUrl variable?

Comment: the pdf dowloaded is not valide and ".pdf" is in $publicUrl

<iframe style="height: 700px;width: 80%;margin-left: 100px;" src="https://testspphicrm.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/test/test.pdf#zoom=100"></iframe>

Comment: Yes i had probleme in url i fixe it and now i can read the pdf after dowload and in iframe i have the message "NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist."

the url : https://storage.googleapis.com/{Bucket}/uploads/signatures/events/congres/congres_5/association_dpss/dpss_8.pdf

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To make a PDF display in the browser, the server must return two headers:

1. `Content-Type: application/pdf` to tell the browser the file is a PDF.
2. `Content-Disposition: inline` to tell the browser to show the PDF instead of saving it.

You can set headers in PHP with the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, but you must do it before sending *any* other content.